# Is quantum tunneling in transistors patterned?

Tags: transistors, cpu

Quantum tunneling is a problem when engineering a nano scale transistor. Generating random numbers is a common issue in computer science. I'm not an expert in either of these fields, but to someone who might be, does it seem plausible that one could make a random number generator that consists of a 50% reliable transistor? Or would patterns arise?

Answer (score 3):

Something very like this is already in use. All transistors generate noise, from a number of effects: http://www.nikhef.nl/~jds/vlsi/noise/sansen.pdf

Intel have a hardware random number generator that uses this: http://electronicdesign.com/learning-resources/understanding-intels-ivy-bridge-random-number-generator

> The core of Ivy Bridge's ES is an RS-NOR latch with the set and reset
>   inputs wired together (red). When the R/S input is de-asserted, the
>   latch becomes metastable, and its output eventually settles to 0 or 1,
>   depending on thermal noise.

It's still quite hard to eliminate various side-channels and effects of temperature and manufacturing variation, but that article gives a well-sourced discussion of why it's believed to be a good random number source.

Answer (score 2):

You would actually not be able to just straight up 'use' a 50% reliable transistor in this way. Two big problems arise: 1) building a reliable detector of an unreliable event, and 2) reliably generating a random event

If you observe a current in the order of a couple hundred electrons per second, you will see that the current that flows is actually more like: 1000 electrons passing through at once, then a whole second of absolutely nothing, then another bunch of electrons. Especially when dealing with tunneling, the tunneling potential is extremely sensitive to both well-known semiconductor properties as well as e.g. piezoelectric effects. This severely reduces the amount of recoverable entropy from tunneling devices for use as a physical RNG. And mind you - this shouldn't surprise you! You are dealing with extremely low amounts of energy, it shouldn't have much entropy to begin with, let alone entropy you can reliably detect and use.

The other problem is that a detector would be pretty hard to construct. The detector would need to reliably amplify a signal that is only a couple electrons in amplitude. This is not a technical challenge per se. We're already able to do this - it's done in every digital camera since halfway the '00s - but the catch is that you need to expend a lot of energy and circuitry to do this. It seems fairly pointless to save on silicon area by using a 1x1nm tunneling diode or quantum-affected transistor, only to blow a couple square millimeters and a couple of milliamps on the readout circuitry. It's a lot better to use a higher power source. Not only will it create more entropy for you, but it's much easier to convert into the digital domain.

I guess that in the end it all comes down to information energy/power. You'll inherently need to spend a certain amount of energy to get a certain amount of entropy. Whether you do that by making a tiny source and a giant readout mechanism or the other way around (or something in between) is a moot point in theory.

There is nothing inherently wrong with a quantum-affected transistor as an RNG source. Sure you're able to use it. Just like you can use pretty much everything in the universe as an RNG with sufficient conditioning. It doesn't matter if patterns arise; you correct for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is already done. Google does its job well:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator#Physical_phenomena_with_quantum-random_properties